# Recommended usage of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

What are recommended uses of a `std::unique_ptr` as to specifically where, when, and how is it is best used?

I discovered:

[About unique_ptr performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138284/about-unique-ptr-performances)

I already know:

1. `std::unique_ptr` was developed in C++11 as a replacement for `std::auto_ptr`
2. That a `std::unique_ptr` has no reference counting and "owns" object it points to
3. There is no copy/assign with a `std::unique_ptr`
4. When I need a unique pointer, `std::unique_ptr` is the go to structure

What I would like to know:

1. Is using a `std::unique_ptr` ever preferable (other than uniqueness) to something
      else? What do I gain in this situation?
2. If so, under what circumstances and when?
3. Given the need for move semantics, would this make a `std::unique_ptr` less favorable
   overall?
4. If a `std::shared_ptr` would suffice for dynamic memory management in nearly every 
      situation, why does having at my disposal a `std::unique_ptr` matter (again, other
      than uniqueness)?

Comment: since the type is called `unique_ptr`, I find it strange you're searching for other use than being unique...

Comment: And [Which kind of pointer do I use when?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8706192/256138)

Comment: @Mushy: The chief question you need to answer is that of ownership. Nothing else matters in the choice of a smart pointer, and that is answered very well in the questions I linked to. The question you linked to had my downvote (from earlier) because it shows nothing definitive at all and asks the wrong question about the "data".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when is probably closest to my question in overall meaning and intent.  I did not see   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when when researching or posting my question from the closest recommendations offered.

Answer (score 26):

In theory, you should use `unique_ptr` for all pointers unless you know you want to share it, in which case you should use `shared_ptr`. The reason is that `unique_ptr` has less overhead since it doesn't count references.

However, a `unique_ptr` is movable but not copyable, so using one as a member variable can require you to write more code (eg a move constructor), passing one by value means you'll need to use `std::move` and so on. As a result some people use `shared_ptr` out of laziness, because it's just easier, and the perf difference may not be significant for their app.

Finally a raw pointer is fine for observation - pointer uses that can never affect lifetime. Careful choice of the right pointer type can give those who read your code a good understanding of what you are doing. For more, see Herb Sutter's essay, [Elements of C++ Style](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/), specifically the "no delete" section.

Comment: `=default` and implicit move members can easily take care of the extra code.

Comment: If you didn't need an explicit move constructor before adding a `unique_ptr`, you don't need an explicit move constructor afterwards. The only situation in which you'd have to write more code is when you'd have done something that disables the implicit move constructor.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm still waiting for =default in my compiler, but yes

Comment: @KateGregory Use another compiler `;-)`