# Could an optimizing compiler remove all runtime costs from std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, unique-ptr

Reading about `std::unique_ptr` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr, my naive impression is that a smart enough compiler could replace correct uses of `unique_ptr` with bare pointers and just put in a `delete` when the `unique_ptr`s get destroyed. Is this actually the case? If so, do any of the mainstream optimizing compilers actually do this? If not, would it be possible to write something with some/all of `unique_ptr`s compile-time safety benefits that could be optimized to have no runtime cost (in space or time)?

Note to those (properly) worried about premature optimization: The answer here won't stop me from using `std::unique_ptr`, I'm just curious if it's a really awesome tool or just an awesome one.

**EDIT 2013/07/21 20:07 EST:**

OK, so I tested with the following program (please let me know if there's something wrong with this):

```
#include <climits>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

static const size_t iterations = 100;

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::rep smart[iterations];
    std::chrono::steady_clock::rep dumb[iterations];
    volatile int contents;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        {
            std::unique_ptr<int> smart_ptr(new int(5));
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < UINT_MAX; j++)
                contents = *smart_ptr;
        }
        auto middle = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        {
            int *dumb_ptr = new int(10);
            try {
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < UINT_MAX; j++)
                    contents = *dumb_ptr;
                delete dumb_ptr;
            } catch (...) {
                delete dumb_ptr;
                throw;
            }
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        smart[i] = (middle - start).count();
        dumb[i] = (end - middle).count();
    }
    std::chrono::steady_clock::rep smartAvg;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::rep dumbAvg;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        smartAvg += smart[i];
        dumbAvg += dumb[i];
    }
    smartAvg /= iterations;
    dumbAvg /= iterations;

    std::cerr << "Smart: " << smartAvg << " Dumb: " << dumbAvg << std::endl;
    return contents;
}
```

Compiling with g++ 4.7.3 using `g++ --std=c++11 -O3 test.cc` gave `Smart: 1130859 Dumb: 1130005`, which means the smart pointer is within 0.076% of the dumb pointer, which is almost surely noise.

Comment: What *else* would a compiler possibly do?! A unique pointer *is* just a single pointer, as far as the data content of the class is concerned.

Comment: What runtime costs does a `unique_ptr` even have? As for space, `sizeof(myuniqueptr)` vs `sizeof(myptr)` are exactly the same for me, 8 bytes for `int`.

Comment: Well, reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138284/about-unique-ptr-performances suggests that some (early?) implementations weren't that way...

Comment: @SheaLevy: Those tests were performed on ***unoptimized builds***. Profiling without optimization is exceedingly pointless.

Comment: Specifically this answer to that question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810087/636917

Comment: @NicolBolas OK, fair enough. I just don't have a general sense right now of what can and can't be optimized, that's why I asked.

Comment: As a concession to my earlier comment, it's certainly *possible* to write a less efficient implementation (as provided in that linked question, namely where an offset adjustment is required for dereferencing), and a *stateful deleter* might cause such a less efficient implementation if the implementation doesn't check whether the deleter is empty (and apply empty-base optimization only when appropriate).

Comment: In case the downvoters are still around, any chance you're willing to explain why? I'd like to avoid posting unwanted questions if possible.

Comment: It seems to me that as of GCC 4.8.1, `std::unique_ptr` is still implemented as an `std::tuple<pointer, deleter>`.

Comment: @SheaLevy: Answers go in the *answer section*, not in the question. That's one reason.

Comment: The code proves nothing.  Volatile will tell the compiler to preserve the loops, but unique_ptr creation and dereferencing will be replaced by repeatedly moving a constant (5 in the case of the first loop) into *contents. You can see this in the generated assembly.  So both loops will spend the same time, but not because unique_ptr is "cheap".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would certainly be my expectation from any reasonably competent compiler, since it is just a wrapper around a simple pointer and a destructor that calls `delete`, so the machne code generated by the compiler for:

```
x *p = new X;
... do stuff with p. 
delete p;
```

and

```
unique_ptr<X> p(new X);
... do stuff with p;
```

will be exactly the same code.

Comment: More like `x *p; try { p = new X; /* ... */ } catch(...) { delete p; throw; }`...

Comment: Does `unique_ptr` really need to `try/catch`? - surely, in both cases, a failure to allocate in `new` will just throw out of the whole function, either with the plain pointer `p` or smart pointer `p` not "constructed" (in a loose sense of constructed in the former case). I guess if the constructor or `X` throws, you need to worry about that...

Comment: It's about exceptions in the rest of your code! (So I should have said `x *p = new X; try { /* ... */ } catch(...) { delete p; throw; }`.)

Comment: Right, so I was hoping to not have any of those... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, the answer is no.

Recall that `unique_ptr` is a template parametrized *not* only on the type of pointer but also on the type of the deleter. Its declaration is:

```
template <class T, class D = default_delete<T>> class unique_ptr;
```

In addition `unique_ptr<T, D>` contains not only a `T*` but also a `D`. The code below (which compiles on MSVC 2010 and GCC 4.8.1) illustrates the point:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct deleter {
    char filler;
    void operator()(T* ptr) {}
};

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(int*) != sizeof(std::unique_ptr<int, deleter<int>>), "");
    return 0;
}
```

When you move a `unique_ptr<T, D>` the cost is not only that of copying the `T*` from source to target (as it would be with a raw pointer) since it must also copy/move a `D`.

It's true that smart implementations can detect if `D` is empty and has a copy/move constructor that doesn't do anything (this is the case of `default_delete<T>`) and, in such case, avoid the overhead of copying a `D`. In addition, it can save memory by not adding any extra byte for `D`.

`unique_ptr`'s destructor must check whether the `T*` is null or not before calling the deleter. For `defalt_delete<T>` I believe, the optimizer might eliminate this test since it's OK to delete a null pointer.

However, there is one extra thing that `std::unique_ptr<T, D>`'s move constructor must do and `T*`'s doesn't. Since the ownership is passed from source to target, the source must be set to null. Similar arguments hold for assignments of `unique_ptr`.

Having said that, for the `default_delete<T>`, the overhead is so small that I believe will be very difficult to be detected by measurements.

Comment: I think it is optimal enough, as long as the size(default_delete) and * operator are zero overhead, unique_ptr is almost a perfect tool to guard the memory holding by raw pointer.